# Commutative free products

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-product

Do there exist any non-trivial groups such that their free product is commutative?

That is, if $G, H$ are non-trivial groups is $G*H$ ever commutative? My thinking is no but I can't really formulate a reason as to why not.

Comment: The way to think about it is that the free product has relations from $G$ and relations from $H$, but it doesn't have any relations governing how elements from $G$ and elements from $H$ interact. So we would never know when two elements commute in this group.

Comment: But does that necessarily mean $gh \ne hg$ for $g \in G, h \in H$?

Comment: Yes (if $g,h$ are non-trivial). Both words are reduced and reduced words in the free product coincide if and only if they coincide as sequences, that is, they have the same length and coincide at each position.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this, which avoids talking about irreducible words and such, is using the universal property:

**Universal Property of free products**: For any group $K$ and any group homomorphisms $\phi_G:G\to K$ and $\phi_H:H\to K$, there exists a unique homomorphism $\phi:G*H\to K$ extending $\phi_G$ and $\phi_H$.

Thus, to prove that nontrivial elements of $G$ do not commute with nontrivial elements of $H$ in the free product, it suffices to find a group $K$ and homomorphisms $\phi_G:G\to K$ and $\phi_H:H\to K$ such that $\phi(g)$ and $\phi(h)$ do note commute for nontrivial $g\in G$ and $h\in H$.

The usual way to construct such things is with semidirect products. However, $G$ does not necessarily act on $H$ (and vice versa), so we need to employ a small trick.

Let $G$ act freely on itself by left multiplication, and consider the induced action of $G$ on the group $H^G$: $g\cdot(h_{g'})_{g'\in G}=(h_{g^{-1}g'})_{g'\in G}$.

Now consider a copy of $H$ in the first entry of $H^G$, i.e., consider the embedding $H\to H^G$, $h\mapsto (h_{g'})_{g'\in G}$, where $h_{g'}=h$ if $g'=1_G$ and $h_{g'}=1_H$ otherwise.

Then we have the crossed product $H^G\rtimes G$, which contains copies of $G$ and $H^G\supseteq H$. For any nontrivial $g\in G$ and $h\in H$, we have, inside this crossed product, with $h=(h_{g'})_{g'}$,
$$ghg^{-1}=g\cdot h=(h_{g^{-1}g'})_{g'\in G}$$.
So $ghg^{-1}$ has $h$ in the $g$-th entry. On the other hand, $h$ has $1_H$ in the $g$-th entry, because $g\neq 1_G$. Since $h\neq 1_H$, these threads are different, i.e., $ghg^{-1}\neq h$ in $H^G\rtimes G$, which means that $g$ and $h$ do not commute in $H^G\rtimes G$.

Comment: One advantage of this approach is that if $G$ and $H$ are both finite then it produces a finite group in which both $G$ and $H$ are subgroups that do not commute with each other. The free product itself is always infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $g$ is an element in $G$ and $h$ is an element in $H$. If $gh=hg$, they should have the same impact on the other elements of the free group. Now $(gh)(h'g')=e$ where $h'$ and $g'$ are the inverses of $h$ and $g$ respectively and $e$ is the identity element. However $(hg)(h'g')$ is not equal to the identity, because it is a reduced word. So, our assumption ($gh=hg$) is not true.